# How to pivot and rename joined level columns when there are missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe. Each id has several codes, each code has stats. Not all id has all the codes others have.
I need to pivot the dataframe so each id will have a single row, with a column for each code-stat pair.

How should I do that most efficiently using pandas 0.24.2 and python 3.6?

Thanks

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13], 'code':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'], 'max':[111, 112, 113, 221, 222, 333], 'min':[10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 33]})

df
```

```
Results in
    id code  max  min
0   11    a  111   11
1   11    b  112   12
2   11    c  113   13
3   12    a  221   21
4   12    b  222   22
5   13    c  333   33
```

I need to convert it to

```
id a_max a_min b_max b_min c_max c_min
11   111    11   112    12   113    13     
12   221    21   222    22  None  None
13  None  None  None  None   333    33
```

**update**
I have a mistake in the code I posted. 
The codes should be 11, 12, 13 and not 10, 11, 12 for code 'a'.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13], 'code':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'], 'max':[111, 112, 113, 221, 222, 333], 'min':[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 33]})
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), then flatten `MultiIndex` and convert index to column by `reset_index`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id','code']).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   id  max_a  min_a  max_b  min_b  max_c  min_c
0  11  111.0   10.0  112.0   11.0  113.0   12.0
1  12  221.0   21.0  222.0   22.0    NaN    NaN
2  13  333.0   33.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

If possible duplicates in pairs is necessary aggregating by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13], 
                   'code':['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'], 
                   'max':[111, 112, 113, 221, 222, 333], 
                   'min':[10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 33]})
print (df)
   id code  max  min
0  11    a  111   10 <--- 11, a
1  11    a  112   11 <--- 11, a
2  11    c  113   12
3  12    a  221   21
4  12    b  222   22
5  13    a  333   33

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='id',columns='code', aggfunc='mean').sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
#alternative
#df1 = df.groupby(['id','code']).mean().unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   id  max_a  min_a  max_b  min_b  max_c  min_c
0  11  111.5   10.5    NaN    NaN  113.0   12.0
1  12  221.0   21.0  222.0   22.0    NaN    NaN
2  13  333.0   33.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Why max_a equals 111.5 for id 11?

Comment: @Portable - It is sample with change data - (111 + 112) / 2 = 111.5

Comment: If I use the following line after the suggested (and correct) block of code: df1 = df1['max_a', 'max_b']         I get an error: "None of [Index(['patient_id', 'max_a', 'max_b'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @Portable - What is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: These columns were missing because the new query didn't include an id with a and b codes. The error message confused me, and your tip helped me understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 step operation to solve that problem, if you only have 2 columns min and max.

```
# convert the data from long to wide format for max and min
df_max = df.pivot(index="id", columns="code", values="max").reset_index()
df_min = df.pivot(index="id", columns="code", values="min").reset_index()

# join the max and min dataframe with a suffix
merged_df = pd.merge(df_max, df_min, on="id", how="outer", suffixes=("_max", "_min"))
```

output:

```
code  id  a_max  b_max  c_max  a_min  b_min  c_min
0     11  111.0  112.0  113.0   11.0   12.0   13.0
1     12  221.0  222.0    NaN   21.0   22.0    NaN
2     13  333.0    NaN    NaN   33.0    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I have the following stats for each code: min, max, mean, median, 25_percentile, 50_percentile, 75_percentile.

Comment: Then its not good idea to create separate dataframe and merge again together. You should prefer the other solution.